# Changing NTP server based on available connections

Tags: debian, time, ntp

Please refer to the illustration.

I have two machines on a LAN, only one of them has an Internet connection (through a different interface).
Server 1 has a garbage hardware clock.
Server 2 has a good hardware RTC.

Unfortunately, the Server 1 usually has an Internet connection, while the one with the good hardware RTC does not, so depending on the Internet connection status, Server 1 is either the most accurate, or highly unreliable.

It is critical both machines are kept in close synchronization with each other.

Is it possible to have the system automatically fail from Scenario 1 to Scenario 2, perhaps through automated adjustments to each machine's stratum?

[image: Scenario 1 vs Scenario 2]

Comment: at a high-level, I'd look at making server 1 use *both* the NTP server (as a low-level stratum) and Server 2 (with a lower stratum) as time servers, using either//both to set its own clock. That way, if the internet connection is good, server 1's ntp client can use that; otherwise, when the NTP server becomes unreachable, it falls back to server 2.

Comment: Jeff, thanks for the quick reply. That's actually what I'm doing now, but I was concerned that once the Internet connection is lost Server 2 will badly drift because it is using Server 1 as it's 'master'. Is there a race condition here, or will the fact Server 1 is using Server 2 prevent this? I guess the more likely scenario is that Server 2 is actually using itself via Server 1...

Comment: Have server 2 keep its own time against its rtc...

Comment: ...but even a good RTC will drift over time, so it will become very inaccurate after several months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are highly unlikely to be allowed to access a Stratum *1* server, unless you're known to the Stratum 1 server administrators and they gave you explicit permission to do so. Having said that, what that server's stratum is doesn't matter for this answer, so I'll refer to that machine as the "low-stratum" server for clarity.

You should configure `server2` to get its time from the low-stratum server, not from `server1`. This will require that it is able (at least for NTP) to access the Internet link on `server1`. If `server2` does not have a link to the Internet with which it would be able to access the low-stratum server, then you can allow it to do that by running the following commands on `server1` (as root):

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s server2 -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s server2 -p tcp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

The first two lines allow NTP traffic from host `server2` *only*. Note: I'm not 100% sure that TCP connections are required, but it shouldn't hurt. You might want to also add `-d lowstratumserver` to those two lines too, so that this machine won't be able to access any other server (just the low-stratum one). The next line allows return traffic from connections that are established. The fourth line enables network address translation. The final line enables IP packet forwarding. With these, `server1` is now a (minimal) router.

If `server2` doesn't have `server1` as its default router, you will also need to add an explicit route for the low-stratum server:

```
ip route add lowstratumserver via server1
```

With that, `server2` will use `server1` as its router for network connectivity to `lowstratumserver`, and its regular router for everything else.

Then, configure `server2` to use the low-stratum server on the Internet as its NTP source, not `server1`.

Finally, configure `server1` so that it connects to `server2`, not the Stratum 1 server on the Internet.

Now `server2` synchronizes with the low-stratum server on the Internet, not with `server1`; and `server1` will synchronize with `server2` always, doing away with the need to add a failover setup (which will be fragile at best).

This will lose you a slight amount of accuracy due to the extra hop, but it's always better to synchronize the machines on your local network to a machine with a good hardware RTC, rather than to a machine with a low-quality one.

Comment: Wouter, I'll give this a shot and report back - thank you very much for the thorough answer.

Comment: Sorry it's so late - but Wouter, this worked *exactly* as you outlined. FWIW, in my instance the tcp rule was not required.